# Using more command

Tags: history, less, pager, more

Is there any case or reason to use "more" unix command instead of "less". As far as I see "less" is "better" in all senses, so does it mean that "more" is a command which has no reason to be used when there's "less"?

Comment: There's also `most`, which may or may not be installed your local Linux machine. It includes a nice status bar and will decompress `gzip`'d files automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `more` command is considerably older than the `less` command ([1978](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_%28command%29) vs [1983ish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29)).  The `less` command was introduced as a 'backwards more' (because you could scroll up).  The `more` command is part of the OS binaries with most modern unix/linux OSs, while `less` is maintained externally as an open source project.

I'll often use `more` on systems with the bare minimum OS installed because `less` isn't available or installed yet.

Comment: And back when "minimum" meant a one- or two-floppy rescue system, of course you used a plain `more` because it was *smaller* than `less`.

Comment: I don't trust those newfangled 1983 commands

Comment: I just looked at what `less` was linked against on my linux system, and saw libpcre, so I guess less also has fancier searching methods too.